# bash list files of a particular naming convention

Tags: bash, ls

Operating System - Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)

I have a directory with thousands of files in it. The file names range anything from a.daily.csv to a.b.daily.csv to a.b.c.daily.csv to a.b.c.d.daily.csv to a.b.c.d.e.daily.csv

The challenge I'm having is in listing just a.daily.csv or a.b.daily.csv and so on. That is to say with "daily.csv" as the fixed part, I would like to be able to wildcard what is in front of it with "." being the delimiter between the fields

I tried a few wildcards such as ? [a-zA-Z0-9] & so on but unable to achieve this. Please could I get some guidance

Please note a,b,c etc are placeholders I'm using to post the question. In real world, a,b,c are alphanumeric words

Example -

```
PAHKY.daily.csv
TYUI.GHJ.WE.daily.csv
WGGH.FGH.daily.csv
98KJL-GHR.YUI.daily.csv
67HJE.HJQ.ATD.HJ.daily.csv
```

If I want to list all those files that are like PAHKY.daily.csv where thre is only one filed (dot being the delimiter) in front of daily.csv, how could I do this?

Comment: would just `ls a.daily.csv` or `ls a.b.daily.csv` won't work?

Comment: I've just updated the question with example data.

Comment: How about simply `echo *.daily.csv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable the `extglob` option:

```sh
$ shopt -s extglob
```

you can use extended pattern matching operators like `*(pattern)` for zero or more of `pattern`. Knowing that `[^.]` matches any character but a dot, this leads to:

```sh
$ ls *([^.]).daily.csv
PAHKY.daily.csv
```

to obtain all `a.daily.csv` files. For the next group:

```sh
$ ls *([^.]).*([^.]).daily.csv
WGGH.FGH.daily.csv  98KJL-GHR.YUI.daily.csv
```

and so on. Replace `*(pattern)` by `+(pattern)` if you want to match one or more of `pattern` instead of zero or more.

Answer (score 0):

You use grep with ls, as grep works well with regex
Try something like this,

```
^a\.b\.c\.data\.csv$
```

```
ls | grep 'Your Expression'
```

Fact, you can even use `find` without piping to `grep`

Comment: Thank you basic func. I've updated the question withe example data

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ls |grep -Po '([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]?)+.daily.csv'
```

**Explanation:**

```
-P, --perl-regexp
-o, --only-matching
[A-Za-z0-9\-\.] --match the group of characters : (A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,.)
()  -- to capture a group
?   -- matches zero or one of the previous RE.
+   -- matches one or more of the previous RE
```

Output:

```
67HJE.HJQ.ATD.HJ.daily.csv
98KJL-GHR.YUI.daily.csv
PAHKY.daily.csv
TYUI.GHJ.WE.daily.csv
WGGH.FGH.daily.csv
```